# Wordpress - Portfolio - Changing Title Length?

Tags: wordpress, portfolio

I've Googled my fingers off but just can't find the solution!  I'm using a Wordpress Child Theme (on top of Cherry) and simply want to change the length of the Title used and displayed in the Portfolio.  It is the default portfolio, not a plug in.

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to provide links due to confidentiality!  Any help appreciated.

Neil.

EDIT - Well I'm not a developer so apologies for my clear lack of detail.  I don't know which part of functions.php controls this post.  I can see it loads theme-portfoliometa.php which has what looks like some likely code but I can't read it well enough to know what's what.

I can manage CSS/HTML but not php.  I can provide a link via PM if anyone has the patience to help.

So far, I inserted a php script I found on another post into my-functions.php (child theme) but that changed the excerpt length of the news (posts).  I've tried looking for '35' in all php files also which is the current limit.

Comment: Can you please post the code inside `functions.php` of the parent theme that creates this custom post type? What have you tried so far? Googling... isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$the_title = esc_attr ( the_title_attribute ( 'echo=0' ) );
$max_length = 50;
$title_length = strlen ( $the_title );

if ( $title_length > $max_length ) {
    $title_excerpt = substr ( $the_title, 0, $max_length ) . '...';
} else {
    $title_excerpt = $the_title;
}
```

This will truncate the title to 50 characters if it is larger and append ...

If the title is <= 50 characters it will just display as normal.

Comment: Ooh that looks sexy :).  I'll try popping it in the functions.php file and if that's the wrong place I'll stick it in all the other files too!  

Thanks Doc!

Comment: Hmm it's increased the field to 39 characters! (including spaces) but I'll take what I can get.  I can also make the titles shorter which in fairness, lines them up a little more.}

Help appreciated all the same Doc.  +1!